# Shortcode not working on static front page

Tags: shortcode, frontpage

A shortcode from a plugin I am trying to use is not working on my static front page, it only shows as plain shortcode text but It works well on all of my other pages.

I'm using Illdy theme, I've already asked about this issue on their forum but I have a feeling that the issue is in my `front-page.php` file. Is there anything missing or extra in my `front-page.php` file that is preventing the shortcode from working?

**UPDATE**: in front-page.php, I changed get_the_content() to the_content() and I fixed my issue. Is this a good fix? Can I feel comfortable in making this change?

Here's my front-page.php:

```
<?php
/**
 *  The template for displaying the front page.
 *
 *  @package WordPress
 *  @subpackage illdy
 */



get_header();


if( get_option( 'show_on_front' ) == 'posts' ): ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <section id="blog">
                    <?php do_action( 'illdy_above_content_after_header' ); ?>
                    <?php
                    if( have_posts() ):
                        while( have_posts() ):
                            the_post();
                            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
                        endwhile;
                    else:
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
                    endif;
                    ?>
                    <?php do_action( 'illdy_after_content_above_footer' ); ?>
                </section><!--/#blog-->
            </div><!--/.col-sm-7-->
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div><!--/.row-->
    </div><!--/.container-->

<?php
else:

    $sections_order_first_section = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_general_sections_order_first_section', 1 );
    $sections_order_second_section = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_general_sections_order_second_section', 2 );
    $sections_order_third_section = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_general_sections_order_third_section', 3 );
    $sections_order_fourth_section = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_general_sections_order_fourth_section', 4 );
    $sections_order_fifth_section = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_general_sections_order_fifth_section', 5 );
    $sections_order_sixth_section = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_general_sections_order_sixth_section', 6 );
    $sections_order_seventh_section = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_general_sections_order_seventh_section', 7 );
    $sections_order_eighth_section = get_theme_mod( 'illdy_general_sections_order_eighth_section', 8 );

    if( have_posts() ):
        while( have_posts() ): the_post();
            $static_page_content = get_the_content();
            if ( $static_page_content != '' ) : ?>
                <section class="front-page-section" id="static-page-content">
                    <div class="section-header">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                </div><!--/.col-sm-12-->
                            </div><!--/.row-->
                        </div><!--/.container-->
                    </div><!--/.section-header-->
                    <div class="section-content">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                                    <?php echo $static_page_content; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            <?php endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;

    if( $sections_order_first_section ):
        illdy_sections_order( $sections_order_first_section );
    endif;

    if( $sections_order_second_section ):
        illdy_sections_order( $sections_order_second_section );
    endif;

    if( $sections_order_third_section ):
        illdy_sections_order( $sections_order_third_section );
    endif;

    if( $sections_order_fourth_section ):
        illdy_sections_order( $sections_order_fourth_section );
    endif;

    if( $sections_order_fifth_section ):
        illdy_sections_order( $sections_order_fifth_section );
    endif;

    if( $sections_order_sixth_section ):
        illdy_sections_order( $sections_order_sixth_section );
    endif;

    if( $sections_order_seventh_section ):
        illdy_sections_order( $sections_order_seventh_section );
    endif;

    if( $sections_order_eighth_section ):
        illdy_sections_order( $sections_order_eighth_section );
    endif;
endif;

get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please post your answer yourself and accept it, feelings has nothing to do with your code, if it works for you share the solution so it can be removed from unanswered solution.

Comment: Saying "Can I feel comfortable in making this change?" was not actually a question about feelings. I wanted to know if this was a reliable and acceptable change. Sure, the change fixed my issue, but I wanted to know if this was an appropriate thing to do to the code and that it suffices as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to change your front-page.php page, you are using the wrong variable.

```
$static_page_content = get_the_content();
```

to

```
$static_page_content = the_content();
```

Edit: I see you just updated your question to this, yes this will work fine. Shouldn't see any negative side effects from this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion and question edits are not considered answers.

Answer (score 0):

Good job you guy's ! I've tried this code and it works perfectly.
I've just need to reduce the width of the front page.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/249024)